# RegEx ignore text inside quoted strings in .net

Tags: .net, regex, quotes

How to ignore text inside a quoted string in .NET.
I have following string

```
This is test, 'this is test inside quote'
```

Say I'm searching for `test` and replacing it should only replace `test` not present inside the quote.

```
This is, 'this is test inside quote'.
```

I m using this to match text inside the quoted text.

```
(["']).*?\1
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use `Regex.Replace()`. The regex would match a non-quoted string followed by a quoted string and the match evaluator would replace `test` in the non-quoted part. Something like this:

```
Regex.Replace("This is test, 'this is test inside quote' test",
              @"(.*?)((?<quote>[""']).*?\k<quote>|$)",
              m => m.Groups[1].Value.Replace("test", "") + m.Groups[2].Value)
```

Group 1 is the non-quoted part, group 2 is the quoted part (or the end of the string). The result of the above is:

```
This is , 'this is test inside quote'
```

Comment: @Ram, if you think an answer actually answers your question and is better than the others, you should mark it as “accepted” by clicking the tick-mark.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following pattern to skip over quoted strings:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"test|(([""']).*?\2)", "$1");
```

On each character of your string the pattern can match the string `"test"`, match and capture a quoted string, or fail. If it does capture the `$1` group it will be preserved after replacement, otherwise the matched string will be removed.

Working example: http://ideone.com/jZdMy

Answer (score 0):

I would extract these quoted substrings into a List (of course if you have more than 1 quotation),create placeholder for later (%1,%2, etc.), execute the regexp, and replace placeholders with list items.

Comment: What if there's `%1` in the original string?

Comment: replaced substrings. If you have more than one quotation, the number would increase. Actually, this is not a regexp, just easier way from regexp hell.

Answer (score -1):

I can see one double quote and one single quote in regEx. Ensure both are single quote. Perhaps you need to escape the single quotes too.  `([\'\']).*?\1`

Comment: What's inside `[]` is a character group and having both `'` and `"` there is fine. Having a character there twice is exactly the same as having it there once.

Comment: Right but it is not just finding ' or ". Should be it something like '[*]'

Comment: `['"]` does exactly that – finds a `'` or a `"`. `[*]` would find just asterisk, not sure what you meant.

Comment: I meant any thing between two single quotes. It was not exact regex.